# Gracefully handling "View State cannot be reconstructed" error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere

My application is on Apache MyFaces V2.0. Application Server is WebSphere V8.0. During security testing using URL like below, application is rendering the error in the browser exposing application server details. I have below entries in web.xml. Please suggest a solution to gracefully handle this scenario.

**Web.xml**

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
<location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/error/error500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

**URL**

> localhost/app/test.xhtml?emailId=test1@abcd.com&clickSubmit=Save&javax.faces.ViewState=83eNclk%2FbIe05NjdSUOQtQqlm5FVhzOBEHXMRHzqXhuC7fG%2BpJS9xRI%2BxN9tCjZIPg2dA3%2B8Xdor%2Bj40Wjiy%2FxO3J%2Bu0lbQJFHXnGNxYwUUh102oPNugRXQAmHNJsjYDnxwh9w%3D%3D

**Error:**

> Error Page Exception
>
> SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your
>   application to handle the Original Exception printed below.
>
> Original Exception:
>
> Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: /app/test.xhtml No saved
>   view state could be found for the view identifier: /app/test.xhtml
>   Error Code: 500 Target Servlet: Faces Servlet Error Stack: 
>   javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:128)
>
> ```
>  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
>
>  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>
>  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189) 
>  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>
>  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>
>  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>
>  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>
>  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.
> ```

Comment: Is `FacesServlet` mapped on `*.xhtml`?

Comment: @BaluC Yes, <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <async-supported>false</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Can the error page be opened individually? I'm not familiar with the later Websphere versions, but it look like that the error page itself contained a bug which makes Websphere unable to open it.

Comment: @BaluC Yes, I could open the error page individually. Updated the error stack